# How to view Gmail using VM in Emacs via Imap?

Tags: email, emacs

I followed instructions at [here](http://codeshop.posterous.com/emacs-vm-config-for-gmail-imap) and now I get the following error when I ran `vm`:

```
vm-imap-protocol-error: IMAP protocol error: "unexpected char (10)"

$ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 11.10
Release:    11.10
$ apt-cache policy vm
vm:
  Installed: 8.1.0-1
  Candidate: 8.1.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 8.1.0-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
$ apt-cache policy stunnel4
stunnel4:
  Installed: 3:4.35-2build1
  Candidate: 3:4.35-2build1
  Version table:
 *** 3:4.35-2build1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vm/+bug/321438) on it. And the solution was to add the following line in `.emacs` -

```
(setq vm-stunnel-program "/usr/bin/X11/stunnel4")
```

Comment: Can I do it in `~/.vm`?

Comment: Tried this in `.emacs` but still get the same error.

Comment: What are the changes did you make between?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this on OSX, and it worked for me, after some IMAP URL wrangling.

What do you have in your .emacs and your .vm? In particular, what are your vm-imap-account-alist and vm-primary-inbox set to?

And, as mentioned by @Bibhas, you need to have a working stunnel program. You can download latest from stunnel.org[1](http://www.stunnel.org)

Comment: I made a typo and put `stunnel` in my `.vm` but `stunnel4` in my `.emacs`.  After correcting, everything works.  Thank you!